# How to create `py_extension`s with common shared libraries containing singleton variables using Bazel?

Tags: python, c++, linker, bazel

I am trying to use Bazel to create two native Python modules that share a large set of existing libraries (LLVM and MLIR) -- including static variables that must be singletons across the two extensions. In a simple case, sharing two libraries would look like this:

```
pyext1.so ---.
              >---> somelib ---> somefile.cpp (static int somevariable)
pyext2.so ---`
```

I am using `py_extension` for the two extensions and `cc_library` for `somelib`. If I understand things correctly, `somefile.cpp` is compiled into an object file, which `cc_library` forwards to any target that depends on it, so the two extensions both eventually contain that object file. I can verify with `nm` that this is, in fact, the case: they both contain a corresponding symbol marked with `B` (for the BSS data section).

The problem with this is that, as Python seems to link its native libraries, the two extensions don't see the symbols of the other one, so there are *two* instances of `somevariable`. Since they are supposed to be singletons, the code breaks.

I have found that producing a shared library with `cc_binary` that contains the common code solves the problem (partially):

```
pyext1.so ---.
              >---> somelib.so ---> somelib ---> somefile.cpp (static int somevariable)
pyext2.so ---`
```

Now, Python still links the two extensions without making their symbols visible to each other but the variables live in `somelib.so`, which is loaded in such a way that its symbols are visible to both. As desired, there is now only one instance of `somevariable` and my code works.

My question is: How can I apply this pattern to a large set of libraries that I may not be able to change? More precisely: How can I create a shared library that contains all symbols of its dependencies and the consumers of that library do *not* contain them?

In the simple example above, my `BUILD` file roughly looks like this:

```py
cc_binary(
    name = "somelib.so",
    linkshared = 1,
    deps = [":somelib"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "somelib",
    src = ["somefile.cpp", "somefile.hpp"],
    deps = [
      # ...
    ],
    alwayslink = 1,
)
```

The `alwayslink` is important here: it makes sure that all symbols from `somefile.cpp` end up in `somelib.so` even if they aren't used in the library itself. However, this does not affect the symbols in `deps`. How can I achieve that?

Note that I can't simply put `alwayslink` to all targets I depend on. Not only are they from a large external project that I might not be able to change, but more importantly, it isn't enough: With above pattern, consumers need to depend on `somelib.so` but *also* on `somefile.hpp` and potentially other header files from `deps`. If they depend on these `deps` and those are marked with `alwayslink` then the symbols from these libraries *end up in the consumers as well*.

What I think I need is a means to get only the headers for the consumers of `somelib.so` and/or only the object files of the `deps` of `somelib` such that I can wrap those into another `cc_library` and mark only that one with `alwayslink`. How could I implement that? (One way is to do it manually like it is done [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/b93eded7b9/utils/bazel/llvm-project-overlay/mlir/build_defs.bzl#L28-L71)) but (1) I have at least hundreds if not thousands of dependent targets and (2) may not be able to change the downstream project.)

**Update:** Another non-solution is to use `cc_shared_library` (which is experimental). That rule makes sure that each object file is only ever compiled into one shared library and still provides all header files to consumers, which sounds promising. However, it cannot be consumed by either `cc_library`, `cc_binary`, or `py_extension`, which complain that a target it creates `does not have mandatory providers: 'CcInfo'`.